# How do I print out a specific column when two other columns are equal in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table that has the following columns:

```
ID | Name | Manager ID
2 | Bob Jones | 3
3 | Sue Smith | 4
```

I want to run a query that will print the manager's name. In the above example:

```
ID | Name | Manager ID | Manager Name
2  | Bob Jones | 3 | Sue Smith
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, on the same table.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This was definitely a brain fog moment today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table can be joined to itself

```
SELECT *
    FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t1.ManagerId= t2.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select x.*
into #temp
from
(
select 2 as ID, 'Bob Jones' as Name, 3 as Manager_ID 
UNION ALL
select 3 as ID, 'Sue Smith' as Name, 4 as Manager_ID 
) x;

select 
    a.*, b.Name as Mananger_name
from
    #temp a
inner join
    #temp b on a.Manager_ID=b.ID
```

[image]